# Can't load trained model with Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

my model (tf.keras.Sequential) was trained in Python, and I converted it into TF.js Layers format by using tfjs.converters.save_keras_model().
I created a server in folder (which contains *.bin files and a 'model.json'), using 'http-server' in cmd.
After that, I run this code to load the model:

```
(async () => {
        const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('http://127.0.0.1:8080/model.json');
        console.log('done');
    })();
```

It doesn't work for me, these 3 errors appear in my console:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/model.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/model.json net::ERR_FAILED
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request for http://127.0.0.1:8080/model.json failed due to error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at tf.min.js:2
```

I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is an issue with CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) - you need more than just simple web server to serve the files.

For any static files (like the bin and json files you have) that you want to use across domains on website etc you need to set the right header for those files by the web server so the browser knows its ok to use on such sites.

This is to do with web security across domains and whilst it catches a lot of folk out its important to have. Not sure what web server you are running but if you are using Express with Node.js then check this simple tutorial:

https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

or this lib:

https://medium.com/@alexishevia/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b

Note the Allow-Origin part which is where you need to set the domain you plan to use it on. You can also use wildcard * to allow all domains if you want anyone to be able to use use those files on their sites too without issue.

Oh and fun fact, if you dont want to deal with a web server at all try Glitch.com which allows you to host experimental projects and upload assets if this is just for fun - it sets all the CORS headers correctly and is easy to use and prototype stuff on. https://glitch.com/@TensorFlowJS

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really helpful for me. I'm new to web programming so it's not easy to find such a solution.

Comment: Most welcome! Once you know the basics though it becomes super powerful - the reach and the scale of the web is truly epic and will pay you dividends in the future for embracing it. Good luck on your journey!